# what is the meaning of Broken pipe Exception?

Tags: java

what is the meaning of broken pipe exception and when it will come?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

A pipe is a data stream, typically data being read from a file or from a network socket.  A broken pipe occurs when this pipe is suddenly closed from the other end.  For a flie, this could be if the file is mounted on a disc or a remote network which has become disconnected.  For a network socket, it could be if the network gets unplugged or the process on the other end crashes.

In Java, there is no `BrokenPipeException` specifically.  This type of error will be found wrapped in a different exception, such as a `SocketException` or `IOException`.

Comment: Nice explanation , yes , it is wrapped in IOException ,but with this clear message as "Broken pipe"  , In log we will get something like this :   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe

Comment: @xyz_scala if this is happening repeatedly, then it's possible one end of the software is closing the socket and you're getting it on the other end, or you're having a hardware failure and you're getting it on both ends

Comment: Broken pipe happens only when you write to a connection that was closed by the other end. When you read from a connection that was closed by the other end, you get end-of-file.

Answer (score 6):

Pipe is basically a communication channel between two processes. So one process writes to the pipe while the other reads from it. 
A broken pipe exception typically means that one process is attempting to read or writ data from a pipe, where as the process on the other end of the pipe has died/been killed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Java.net ?

If you closed the connection, then you need to open a new socket
before you can send more data.

or your connections is been rejected

Comment: If he had closed his own connection he would have got 'socket closed'. If his connection attempt had failed he wouldn't have even got a `Socket.` In neither case would he have got 'broken pipe'. There is no evidence in the question as to whether or not he is using `java.net.`