# Check for Broken Pipe only when IOException is thrown

Tags: java, android, ioexception, broken-pipe

When writing to an `OutputStream` it will throw a `IOException` exception if the remote machine down, or has disconnected. Now, I want to call a specific method when only (and only) the pipe is broken. The problem is that `IOException` does not have a `code` or `errno` property to check for this error. And the only way I was able to achieve this is by

```
        try {
            stream.write(message.getBytes("UTF8"));
            stream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (e.getMessage().equals("sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)")) {
                // perform a specific action
            } else {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Obviously this is not the perfect way to achieve such a thing. Any suggestion for an efficient solution?

Answer (score 1):

[As mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3751722/3143670)

> In Java, there is no `BrokenPipeException` specifically. This type of
>   error will be found wrapped in a different exception, such as a
>   `SocketException` or `IOException`.

So you can achieve the same using `String#contains()` method

```
if(e.getMessage().contains("Broken Pipe")){
// Do Whatever you want to do 
}
```